# Using VC10 dll (outlook addin) with Outlook 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, outlook-addin

I have installed MS Outlook 2010 in Windows 7 (64 bit) system. 
The dependency walker shows the outlook.exe dependency on MSVCR90.dll. I have developed an outlook add-in using VS2010 development environment, hence my add-in is dependent on MSVCR100.dll.

Question is:
Can I load the dll as outlook add-in (developed in VC100 runtime), with MS Outlook 2010 (which is in some VC90 runtime)? I am hoping that mix and match of runtimes may result in heap corruption somewhere down the lane if i start using new/delete.

Answer (score 1):

It should work. At link time, Outlook used the import library for MSVCR90.DLL, which means its new and its delete are resolved against that implementation, while you used the MSVCR100.DLL import library so your new and your delete are resolved against that.

Now there *would* be a problem if Outlook ever tried to pass one of your pointers to its `delete`, but it won't. You probably communicate with outlook via COM, which means allocations across the boundary go via `IAlloc`.